# Angular 2 - Unhandled promise rejection, not a known element

Tags: angular

I have a sidebar component, and within that I use sidebar-item components to fill the

Here is my sidebar-item meta data:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-sidebar-item',
  templateUrl: 'sidebar-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['sidebar-item.component.css'],
})
```

Here is the parent sidebar components meta:

```
@Component({
 moduleId: module.id,
 selector: 'sd-sidebar',
 templateUrl: 'sidebar.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['sidebar.component.css']
})
```

It also imports the sidebar item component.
import { SidebarItemComponent } from './sidebar-item/sidebar-item.component';

The html of the sidebar component is as follows:

The errors points to here.

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'sd-sidebar-item' is not a known element:
1. If 'sd-sidebar-item' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

My sidebar item module is as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';
import { SidebarItemComponent } from './sidebar-item.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule],
  declarations: [SidebarItemComponent],
  exports: [SidebarItemComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class SidebarItemModule { }
```

My sidebar component module is as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar.component';
import { SidebarItemModule } from './sidebar-item/sidebar-item.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule],
  declarations: [SidebarComponent],
  exports: [SidebarComponent, SidebarItemModule],
  providers: []
})
export class SidebarModule { }
```

My main root app module is as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

import { HeaderModule } from './header/header.module';
import { SidebarModule } from './sidebar/sidebar.module';
import { ChatModule } from './chat/chat.module';

import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes), HeaderModule, SidebarModule, ChatModule, SharedModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed my sidebar.module.ts to:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule, SidebarItemModule],
  declarations: [SidebarComponent],
  exports: [SidebarComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class SidebarModule { }
```